# pyautogui pixelMatchesColor returns " 'int' object is not callable" error

Tags: python-3.x, int, callable, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui to check if a pixel matches color, like in Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 18.

My program, in its entirety (and after restarting IDLE) is:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(50,100 (255,255,255))
```

That's it.

Returns the following:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I looked over the other "int is not callable" threads and they seem to have to do with variables named like functions.  Which isn't the case here.  I also checked the documentation here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html and I don't see what is going wrong.

Can anyone please tell me what I am overlooking?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a comma between 100 and the tuple. Then it should work okay, since pixelMatchesColor takes an x-coordinate, a y-coordinate, and an RGB tuple. As-is, Python thinks you're trying to call 100 as a function, with parameters 255, 255 and 255.

```
pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(50,100,(255,255,255))
```

Should work. You don't have a variable named like a function, but you involuntarily treated a constant/integer like a function, with the parentheses right after.

A similar error is below:

```
x = [1, 2]
print(x(1))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Or, the reverse, using parentheses on a function

```
def a(x): return False
print(a[True])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

I still get the "Object is not callable/subscriptable" error a lot, but I'm getting used to checking for proper use of parentheses/brackets.